# Correct way to shutdown smack client deployed on tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, smack

I'm developing application that deployed on Tomcat. I'm using Smack to implement CCS FCM over XMPP. I'm monitoring shutdown hook and on shutdown runs connection.disconnect(). However on undeploy I have got this trace in catalina logs.

```
10-Oct-2017 17:44:06.952 WARNING [https-jsse-nio2-8081-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [wfmserver] appears to have started a thread named [Smack-Ping 0 (0)] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
10-Oct-2017 17:44:06.952 WARNING [https-jsse-nio2-8081-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [wfmserver] appears to have started a thread named [Smack-Incoming Processor 0 (0)] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.take(ArrayBlockingQueue.java:403)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
10-Oct-2017 17:44:06.953 WARNING [https-jsse-nio2-8081-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [wfmserver] appears to have started a thread named [Smack-Single Threaded Executor 0 (0)] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
10-Oct-2017 17:44:06.953 WARNING [https-jsse-nio2-8081-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [wfmserver] appears to have started a thread named [MappedByteBufferSource Async Flush Thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
10-Oct-2017 17:44:06.953 WARNING [https-jsse-nio2-8081-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [wfmserver] appears to have started a thread named [Smack-Cached Executor 0 (0)] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:460)
java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362)
java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:941)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1073)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

So, my question is how I should shutdown smack? How I can prevent memory leaks?

Comment: Sorry - how is a shutdown hook relevant in a web application? You need a [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/index.html?javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html). See [this tutorial](http://javaevangelist.blogspot.co.uk/2013/11/java-ee-7-tip-of-day-web-application.html).

Comment: @BoristheSpider I'm incorrectly said. To be clear, I'm using Spring `@PreDestroy`. The point of a question is how to force Smack to stop all of its threads to prepare my application for undeploy.

Comment: i think first logout, than disconnect and you are ready to go.